# IF in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

del=0 - not deleted, del=1 - sender and reciever deleted message, del=2 - sender deleted message, del=3 - receiver deleted message. My code is:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    (`from` = :owner AND `to` = :partner) OR (`from` = :partner AND `to` = :owner) AND IF(`from` = :owner,`del`=3 OR `del`=0,`del`=2 OR `del`=0)
ORDER BY
    id DESC
```

But it does not work. Help please.

Comment: How does it not work? Does it throw an error? Does it return the wrong results, no results?

Comment: What database system are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQLServer?

Comment: It  gives me all messages as if there is no any code after '(from = :owner AND to = :partner) OR (from = :partner AND to = :owner)'. PDO

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the use of backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have run into the problem that the `IF()` function returns either a string or numeric value. But you seem to expect that it returns a boolean value. (SQL has not boolean data type.)

So you have to use an alternative to `IF()`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    (`from` = :owner AND `to` = :partner)
 OR (`from` = :partner AND `to` = :owner)
    AND (`from` = :owner AND `del` IN (0, 3)
        OR `from` <> :owner AND `del` IN (0, 2))
ORDER BY
    id DESC
```

This should be identical if `from` and `:owner` cannot be NULL. Otherwise some NULL handling is required for `from <> :owner`.

BTW.: Do you really want to test for the `del` flag only for the second part of the OR expression? Because that's how SQL would evaluate it (AND before OR).

**Update**

From your comment, I must assume that the evaluation order is indeed wrong. Therefore, I'm changing it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages
WHERE
  (
    (`from` = :owner AND `to` = :partner)
    OR (`from` = :partner AND `to` = :owner)
  )
  AND (`from` = :owner AND `del` IN (0, 3)
      OR `from` <> :owner AND `del` IN (0, 2))
ORDER BY
    id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your version does not work too. It (and my version too) gives me all messages as if there is no any code after '(`from` = :owner AND `to` = :partner)
 OR (`from` = :partner AND `to` = :owner)'. My english is bad so please write in intermediate level :)

Comment: See my update. The AND clause for the checking the `del` flag should probably be applied to all messages.